# Laravel 5: Sending Email

Tags: php, email, smtp, laravel-5

I am trying to send an email in laravel application.
Here is my `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=ehsan.sani91@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

And here is the `Mail::send` method:

```
Mail::send('email', ['name' => "EE"], function($m){
            $m->to('ee@dx.com', 'Malik')->subject('Subjet of the email');
        });
```

And here is the error:

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. s16sm7748968wib.16 - gsmtp"
```

Any help?

Comment: where are you using this code, local or server?

Comment: If u mean the Mail::send(---) code, then i m using it in Controller.

Comment: I mean... u r on localhost or Server!?

Comment: It's just an authentication error.  I would suggest following the instructions of the error message `530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. s16sm7748968wib.16 - gsmtp`.

Comment: A quick google get's this... http://richardwillia.ms/blog/2010/12/swift-mailer-starttls - I hope it helps

Comment: yeah, i m on localhost..

Comment: I am not using swift mailer @Ash, I am using laravel, so how to deal with starttls problem in laravel, any idea?

Comment: Laravel uses Swift mailer which is also a Symfony component.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, I got it. Infact the email was not authenticated because that email required a mobile phone authentication after login. changing to other email address that required just login credentials, it worked.

```
.env
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@host.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 2):

GMail SMTP requires encryption. Try changing setting as following.

```
 MAIL_PORT=465
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: tried with no benefit, giving the error: Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. w8sm20719292wja.15 - gsmtp
"

Comment: what is your driver settings `'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp')` in mail config??

Comment: This is the driver settings: `'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp')`

Comment: This is host: `'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com')` and this is port: `'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465)` in mail config file

Comment: other settings like driver, port, host in config??

Comment: your `.env` file `MAIL_HOST` should be this: `MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com`. The `env()` function will attempt to load a variable from the `.env` or use the default:  `env('KEY', 'the default')`.  (this is for someone who comes here with the same issue)

Answer (score 1):

I made the following mistake:
I did not actually include the

```
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION'),
```

to the array return in mail.php. I did include my host, port, username and password in the mail.php but not the encryption method (the encryption method I only included in the .env file), so trying out these mentioned solutions did bring a change in the error messages outcome, created a bigger confusion, but none solved the problem. Hope this helps someone!