# Error with sending password reset email Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, email

This is the first time to configure mail to send password reset. I checked less secured to be active. I am getting this error

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 
Must issue a STARTTLS command first. g63sm30213782wme.11 - gsmtp"
```

here is my configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=hmshafik10@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Update
Tried to use set mail data in config/mail.php. Now I am getting this error

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 
Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError u189sm6330267wmg.18 - gsmtp"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel SwiftMailer : Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469770/laravel-swiftmailer-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-530-with-messag)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Sending Email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378357/laravel-5-sending-email)

Answer (score 0):

It could be also that you actually don't get those variables from .env file.

When editing .env file you must clear cache with

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and maybe the best thing would be to restart the app if you are running it with

```
php artisan serve
```

then stop it and rerun again