# Expected Response code 250 but got code " ", with messae laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sendmail

I have tested my smpt setting on other localhost server, It is working well!
But on my localhost i am geting this error

my Setting

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Please suggest me where i am wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Sending Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378357/laravel-5-sending-email)

Comment: change port to 587 and emcryption to tls

Comment: Not working with these changes :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make these changes

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_PORT=587
```

Run this command

```
sudo php artisan config:cache
sudo php artisan cache:clear
```

restart server and run now