# How solve this error ( mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i2sm7399406pjt.19 - gsmtp )

Tags: php, laravel

I has this error when try register

```
mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. k1sm2231247pjj.54 - gsmtp
```

my php.ini is
[image]

my env is

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I dont know why this happen
can someone explain me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5: Sending Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378357/laravel-5-sending-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working with `SSL` so, check your `PHP` installation to make sure you can use that protocol, check if your `PHP` supports it.
If it does, try changing your `.env`, changing the line  `MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com` to `MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com`.
If this doesn't solve your problem, try modifying `SMTP=ssl` in your `php.ini` to `SMTP=ssl://smtp.gmail.com`.

Comment: If the configuration is currently done using environment variable, one should not edit the core PHP configuration to change this

Comment: @NicoHaase if you check his `php.ini` file, you'll see it's not properly configured. Anyway, I just figured out he has a possible error in `.env`, updating to add it to the answer.